# qt designed how to create colored panels?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Qt5 QT Designer 5.11.2. Ultimately the underlying program will be written for PyQt.

This Photoshop mockup shows what I am trying to accomplish. I want the background of my Main Window to be split into sections by background color. The widgets are contained in various horizontal and vertical layouts. The layouts themselves do not have visual properties such as background colors. I thought of putting labels or frames behind the widgets, but QT Designer incorporates them into the layouts and shifts things around so that the added widget doesn't overlap the prior widgets.

How should I do this?

[image: Phtoshop Mockup]

Comment: @eyllanesc -- I know we're not supposed to say "thanks" but I want to acknowledge the significant effort you put into creating this answer. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the layouts point out, they are not visual elements, so in this case you can use a QWidget as a container and set the background color. To manage the size relationship you can use the strecth of each column of the layout.

Considering the above, I have created the following design:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>614</width>
    <height>425</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0,1">
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="0,0,0,0">
     <property name="leftMargin">
      <number>6</number>
     </property>
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>6</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>6</number>
     </property>
     <property name="bottomMargin">
      <number>6</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start Up</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Scan</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Reports</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Shut Down</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3" stretch="0,1">
     <property name="spacing">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">.QWidget{background-color: rgb(143, 238, 234);}</string>
       </property>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Operator</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">.QWidget{background-color: rgb(159, 215, 236);}

QRadioButton {
    color:   black;
}
QRadioButton::indicator {
    width:                  10px;
    height:                 10px;
    border-radius:          7px;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:checked {
    background-color:       black;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}

QRadioButton::indicator:unchecked {
    background-color:       white;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}

QCheckBox::indicator {
    width:                  10px;
    height:                 10px;
    border-radius:       2px;
}
QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
    background-color:       black;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {
    background-color:       white;
    border:                 2px solid white;
}
</string>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" columnstretch="0,0">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>20</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>20</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>20</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>20</number>
          </property>
          <item row="2" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>132</width>
              <height>16777215</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;Election Title, &lt;/span&gt;(e.g. November 2019)&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="wordWrap">
             <bool>true</bool>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="2" column="1">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
            <property name="leftMargin">
             <number>20</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
              <property name="styleSheet">
               <string notr="true"/>
              </property>
              <property name="text">
               <string>11</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
              <property name="text">
               <string>14</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_3">
              <property name="text">
               <string>17</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_4">
              <property name="text">
               <string>21</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_5">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Others</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
            <property name="text">
             <string>&lt;b&gt;Path to images&lt;/b&gt;</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="3" column="1">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
          </item>
          <item row="4" column="1">
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
          </item>
          <item row="4" column="0">
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
            <property name="text">
             <string>&lt;b&gt;Path to external drive</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Double Sided</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6" stretch="0,1">
            <property name="spacing">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <item>
             <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
              <property name="text">
               <string/>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
              <property name="text">
               <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Check this &lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;box &lt;/span&gt;only if this &lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;first run &lt;/span&gt;of this election and &lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600; font-style:italic;&quot;&gt;any old material should be deleted&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>98</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
          <item>
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>40</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Start Up</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Exit</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]